# How to display all YouTube videos from specific channel in Android app

Tags: android, youtube

How I display all YouTube videos from specific channel in Android app .I m using Android studio to develop Android App...and New video from channel automatically display in Android app.... Please Help Me

Answer (score 0):

```
    String youtubeURL = "https://www.youtube.com/user/androiddevelopers";
    Intent youtubeIntent=null;
    try {
        youtubeIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        youtubeIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
        youtubeIntent.setData(Uri.parse(youtubeURL ));
        startActivity(youtubeIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {  // If youtube app not available then using browser it should open
        youtubeIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        youtubeIntent.setData(Uri.parse(youtubeURL ));
        startActivity(youtubeIntent);
    }
```

Comment: Please Tell All step to taken to get all video from specific channel in Android app ...I m using Android studio @user3360390 #user3360390