# Is there any way to retrieve data of subscribed channel from youtubeintents?

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I am opening youtube app from my application from below code. i am having an problem to retrieve data of channel like user subscribed channel or not.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/**YOURCHANNEL**"));
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
startActivity(intent);
```

I am facing difficulty to retrive data from onActivityResults. I am not sure how can i get data of subscribed channel and other detail.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == Code)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked this [SO related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44801321/how-to-display-all-youtube-videos-from-specific-channel-in-android-app)?

Comment: @jess yes, i have checked it but not sure about how to get callback data like "user subscribed channel or other activity he/she did from youtube app"